# How to time functions in Linux Kernel's start_kernel function?

Tags: time, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to figure out the time function calls take inside Linux kernel's start_kernel function.

Why this is a problem is because the kernel would not boot if I put a `ktime_get()` function call before the timekeeping_init() function call inside that same function.

In my setup I think most likely the kernel spends a lot of time inside `mm_init()`. But I can not verify due to the above mention problem.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This early in the boot there's not really much that's available. `printk` should work, though.

If you're on x86, you could use `rdtsc()`. There's only 1 CPU running at this time, so the usual warnings about confusing results don't apply yet.